# Get current playing track info from all the available android devices

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I m welling to get current playing track info from all the available android devices.Therefore i have tried out this code and it works fine in the emulator or with any nexus phone but as soon as i tried it out on an xperia phone it doens work and it doesnt get any informations back ! 
I think it is not able to detect the walkman media player.

```
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("fm.last.android.playbackpaused");
    iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.miui.player.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.htc.music.playstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.spotify.music.playbackstatechanged");
    iF.addAction("com.spotify.music.metadatachanged");
    iF.addAction("com.rhapsody.playstatechanged");

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
}

public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        boolean playing = intent.getBooleanExtra("playing", false);
        String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
        Log.v("tag ", action + " / " + cmd);
        String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
        String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
        String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
        Log.i("tag", "This is the track information:");
        Log.v("tag", artist + ":" + album + ":" + track);
        Toast.makeText(TrackInformations.this, track, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I think i m missing something because soundcloud player is not detectable as well.

Comment: There is no requirement for any of those `Intent` actions to work, or for other players to send any broadcasts related to track information.

Comment: Can you explain more plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's beacuse the Xperias have a different Walkman App.

I tested with this intent and it works:

```
com.sonyericsson.music.playbackcontrol.ACTION_TRACK_STARTED
```

The intent extras are different, the track info is on a Map, you need to debug it and see what you neeed.

A manifest from a Xperia Walkman App( in case you need more filters) :

http://pastebin.com/cDNJJYGc

Have fun!

Comment: Thanx for the response :) i tried it out now it works but it returns null for everything V/tag﹕ null:null:null

Comment: You need to debug the intent and see where to get them, because the strings that you need are in a Map in the extras, not in the extra strings that you are using.

Comment: sorry but i m a really begginer here,how exactly should i debug the intent ?

Comment: Follow this guide https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html . Put a breakpoint in  String action = intent.getAction(); and evaluate the intent you receive